# Difficulty in merging two sorted arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I wrote this function for merging two sorted arrays in my merge sort implementation but I am always getting wrong ouput.

```
void merge(int array[],int l,int m,int r)
{
   int i,j,k,n1,n2;
   n1=m-l+1;
   n2=r-m;
   int left[n1],right[n2];
   for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
   left[i]=array[l+i]
   for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
   right[i]=array[m+i+1]
   i=0; j=0;
   for(k=l;k<r;k++)
   {
       if(left[i]<=right[j])
       {
         array[k]=left[i];
         i+=1;
       }
        else
       {
         array[k]=right[j];
         j+=1;
       }
}
```

SAMPLE INPUT : 4 6 3 1 2

OUTPUT : 1 2 3 0 2

I am not able to figure out where is it going wrong . I followed Merge-Sort algorithm given in Cormen. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: I don't know if this solves it but **please** format your code correctly as you are missing several semicola.

For example: Your shortened ``for``-loops are missing the semicola which end the loop.

Comment: provide me and input to check it if you can.

Comment: Sample Input :- 5 4 1 11 3 9 2 Output giving :- 1 2 0 2 0 1 2

Comment: Don't understand your question. You say there's two arrays but only one input... Do you mean you sort the contents of one array into another array?

Comment: it is just the merge function that is used in Merge-Sort algorithm @FiddlingBits

Comment: The characters `'l'` and `'1'` look very similar.  `'l'` really shouldn't be used.

Comment: @AbinashPanigrahi are you sure of your input and output , is this merge function ?

Comment: I gave another sample input and its output given by my code in my earlier comment. Please suggest any errors found.

Comment: @mohaned i'm getting this output only

Comment: Provide a `main` so this is a working program.

Comment: I am amazed at the dynamic allocation of memory occurring at `int left[n1], right[n2]`. If this indeed is `C`, I don't know how this works.

Comment: @wookie919 This works in C of C99 later to say the VLA (Variable Length Array).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
for(k=l;k<r;k++)
{
    if(left[i]<=right[j])
    {
      array[k]=left[i];
      i+=1;
    }
     else
    {
      array[k]=right[j];
      j+=1;
    }
}
```

to

```
for(k=l;k<=r;k++){
    if(j>=n2 || i<n1 && left[i] <= right[j])
        array[k] = left[i++];
    else
        array[k] = right[j++];
}
```